# long running process for worker processes to respond to rabbitmq messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

My web application is writing messages to rabbitmq.  Example, a user wants to export their data, so I write this message to the queue.  The web application is not java based.

Now I am looking for suggestions on how to create an environment for responding to these messages i.e. worker processes

I want to be able to have multiple worker processes responding to new messages in the queue, and be able to tweak the # of worker processes to respond to demand etc.

Are there any java frameworks that are long running processes?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a grid of working processes to respond to requests available in that rabbitmq. As by frameworks for handling this you could use [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com/), an Open Source Grid/Cloud infrastructure that would allow you to distribute the requests to a number of # worker processes. Another similar option is [Condor](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/). Both resolve similar issues but GridGain is more Java oriented.